# Yii/PHP, year dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii

So, basically I have this piece of code:

```
<?php echo '<strong>Y: </strong>'.$form->dropDownList($model, 'year', array('2015'=>'2015','2014'=>'2014')); ?>
```

As you can see, I have a very manual way of adding in the years. Is there a way for me to add it in automatically every year? Or maybe a year range?

Any advice would be fully appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this function in your model

```
public function getYearsList() {
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $yearFrom = 2013;
    $yearsRange = range($yearFrom, $currentYear);
    return array_combine($yearsRange, $yearsRange);
}
```

And in your form call it like this:

```
$form->dropDownList($model, 'year', $model->getYearsList());
```

Read about php's [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<strong>Y: </strong>'.$form->dropDownList($model, 'year', array(date("Y")=>date("Y"),date("Y")-1=>date("Y")-1,date("Y")-2=>date("Y")-2,date("Y")-3=>date("Y")-3 )); ?>
```

I know this is still not fully automated. But it still updates itself every year.